# Is there a way to know which VIPs are in my cargo bay?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've received various VIPs from mission rewards, usually while I still have crates of a different VIP left over. Currently I have some Level Movers, then some Recruiters, and now more LM's. Is there a way to know what's in each before opening? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No way that I know of, except writing down their positions. The new arrivals always go to the end, and if you take something from the middle, everything after shifts up by one slot.